# the_tags() with ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm new to php and I want to now if it's possible to add a ACF field as a parameter to a function in WordPress.

I have a multisite and my intention is to permit translations to the text before the tags shown on posts.

I added the field `tags_text` with ACF on my home to enter the translations and then I tried:

```
<?php the_tags(the_field("tags_text", $home->ID), ", ", "<br />"); ?>
```

and

```
<?php the_tags(get_field("tags_text", $home->ID), ", ", "<br />"); ?>
```

But this is simply bringing the default value to the page.

How can I bring the value entered at the home ACF field?

Comment: `get_field` will return value of field that you want

Comment: No @AliQorbani. I still got the same results

Comment: is your code in the loop ?

Comment: if it is in loop check if correctly saved field or not. `var_dump(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'tags_text'));`.

if it returns correct answer it should work